# Putting AngularDart components in subfolders when routing

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-dart-routing

According to [this tutorial](https://webdev-dartlang-org-dev.firebaseapp.com/angular/guide/router/1#libsrcroutesdart), when defining routes in Angular for Dart you need to import the `template.dart` files of the relevant components:

```
import 'crisis_list_component.template.dart' as clct;
import 'hero_list_component.template.dart' as hlct;
```

I have put my components in a subfolder of the folder where this code resides. I have the import code in `lib/src/routes.dart`:

```
import 'components/foobar/foobar_component.template.dart' as fct;
```

and a Foobar component in `lib/src/components/foobar/foorbar_component.dart`.

When I have the `foobar_component.dart` code in `src` (i.e. the same folder as `routes.dart`) there's no problem. But when I move it to its own subfolder, I get the error:

> Unable to find modules for some sources [...] Please check the following imports: `import 'components/foobar/foobar_component.template.dart'`

How do I get it to find the component in its subfolder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
import '../../components/foobar/foobar_component.template.dart' as fct;
```

but usually, it is better to not use `../` in imports and instead use package imports

```
import 'package:my_package/web/src/components/foobar/foobar_component.template.dart' as fct;
```

where `my_package` is the string used in `name: ...` in your `pubspec.yaml` and `lib/` is skipped in the path to the imported file.

Comment: I tried `import 'web:src/components/...` but I got the error 'Unsupported operation: Cannot resolve web:src/components/[...]; only "package" and "asset" schemes supported'

Comment: Did you name you project `web`? It's a bit difficult to make concrete suggestions because your question inly provides partial paths. If you'd add full paths to importing and importing files (relative to the directory that contains `pubspec.yaml`, I might be able to make better suggestions.

Comment: Yes, the project is called `web`. `pubspec.yaml` is in the root. `routes.dart` is in `lib/src`, and the component is in `lib/src/components/[name]`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake (kinda blackout ;-) ). I updated my answer.